# How to configure Gemfire Locators and Server persistent path from eclipse + Spring data

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am beginner to gemfire, I have installed gemfire 8 on windows able to start Locators and servers and able perform some basic operations. However there are few things below, need of your suggestions for the same.

1) When we start Locator, Server from gfsh command, folders are created by default in bin folder of installation directory, But when I start locators from eclipse using Spring Data using below config prop, I don't know where this default locators folders are generated

```
<util:properties id="gemfireProperties">
    <prop key="name">Locator(Dev)</prop>
    <prop key="mcast-port">0</prop>
    <prop key="locators">D******7[1099]</prop>
    <prop key="log-level">warning</prop>
    <prop key="http-service-port">8181</prop>
    <prop key="jmx-manager">true</prop>
    <prop key="jmx-manager-port">1199</prop>
    <prop key="jmx-manager-start">true</prop>
    <prop key="start-locator">D******7[1099]</prop>
</util:properties>
```

2) How to start servers using configuration from eclipse+Spring Data and configuration of generated folder by the server.

Answer (score 1):

Gfsh will automatically create a directory based on the "member name" (given with the '--name' option to either the 'start server' or 'start locator' commands) if the '--dir' option was not explicitly specified.

I.e., you could do something like...

```
gfsh>start server --name=Example ... --dir=/home/jdoe/GemFire/servers/X
```

This command will start a Server with a member name "Example" in /home/jdoe/GemFire/servers/X.

Gfsh contains the logic to ensure the server is run with a working directory of '/home/jdoe/GemFire/servers/X', implemented with the [ProcessBuilder.directory(:File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) method for configuring and forking the GemFire JVM process (e.g. Server).

See Apache Geode (GemFire's open source core) source code for specific implementation details, [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode/blob/develop/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/management/internal/cli/commands/LauncherLifecycleCommands.java#L1524-1534), [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode/blob/develop/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/management/internal/cli/commands/LauncherLifecycleCommands.java#L1587) and [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode/blob/develop/gemfire-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/management/internal/cli/commands/LauncherLifecycleCommands.java#L1606-1608).

When using your IDE (Eclipse, IDEA, etc) to launch/run a GemFire process (Locator|Server), I usually create a "run" directory manually and then set my "run profile" to run the GemFire process from that directory.[image]